# MVP Pattern Property Set or get

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvp

I am implementing an MVP pattern in asp.net and am confused with a lot of examples on the web .

I see IEnumerable implemented as get; and some times as set; also in other scenarios I see a method void SetCategories(IEnumerable categories);

My Question is for the contract for view (ex:IView) , that shows a list of Categories IEnumerable categories

1) When should I implement `void SetCategories(IEnumerable<Category> categories);`

---

2) When should I Implement `IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }`

---

3)  When should I Implement `IEnumerable<Category> Categories {  set; }`

Answer (score 0):

1 and 3 are very similar, they provide write-only access to the categories. If your presenter does **not** need to read the Categories collection, then you should use 1 or 3.

Which one? This [code analysis rule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327) might apply here.

> If replacing the collection is a goal, the preferred design pattern is to include a method to remove all the elements from the collection and a method to re-populate the collection.

However, in MVP the use of properties over methods is more common (which is probably why you've seen examples of all three scenarios.) So it's really a question of preferred style.

Option 2 provides all the above as well as read access to the property. You need this if the presenter must look into the collection and read a value from it (or all the values). I think the preferred pattern here would be a property to get either the entire collection in a read-only state or the selected category ie. a single `Category`.

- If you need read and write access, option 2 will work but it will
  offend fxCop.
- If you just need write access, option 1 will please fxCop